# Realm file management

Tags: ios, swift, realm

We have been using Realm for a while and some of our users have been experiencing some data loss related to Realm. We think we have narrowed it down to our compaction method for when the file gets too big. We would like to ask for a little advice on if this is the proper way to recreate our Realm file. This method is called on applicationDidEnterBackground.

We wrote a sample of what we are doing below:

```
public static func compact() {
    // Get the original file path
    let configuration = RealmSampleClient.shared.config
    guard let originalFileURL = configuration.fileURL else {
        return
    }
    // check if the file size is bigger than 10mb, if not return
    guard let attr = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: originalFileURL.absoluteString),
        let fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as? UInt64,
        fileSize > 500_000_000 else {
            return
    }

     // create a filepath for a copy
    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
    let dateString = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: date)).realm"
    let copyFileURL = originalFileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(dateString)

     // copy the Realm file
    do {
        let realm = try Realm(configuration: configuration)
        try realm.writeCopy(toFile: copyFileURL, encryptionKey: configuration.encryptionKey)
    } catch {
        return
    }

     // remove the old file and copy the new one
    do {
        removeRealmFile(at: originalFileURL)
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: copyFileURL, to: originalFileURL)
    } catch {
    }
    // remove a copy if it exists
    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copyFileURL.path) else { return }
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: copyFileURL)
    } catch {
    }
}

private static func removeRealmFile(at url: URL = databaseUrl) {
        let realmURLs = [
            url,
            url.appendingPathExtension("lock"),
            url.appendingPathExtension("note"),
            url.appendingPathExtension("management"),
        ]
        realmURLs.forEach { URL in
            guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: URL.path) else { return }
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL)
            } catch {
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks your your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We refactored the flow of our app a bit and it has seemed to solve our problems. It was related to accessing realm too soon during the startup process, possible on multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no kind of compacting code here, only a copy of the database file. So I assume you have left that out to keep the code compact here.

Anyway, you do this operation when the app enters background mode. Do you register a background task for that? If the compacting operation takes too much time the task gets killed by iOS, I think this is the problem.

You can explicitly ask the OS for more background execution time with `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask` but this is also a very time limited amount, usually 3 minutes.

But this is all digging in the dark, you should post more code to see how your background task is set up.

Answer (score 0):

As per Realm doc, it's recommended to wrap your code with autoreleasepool, like this

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm(configuration: configuration)
    try realm.writeCopy(toFile: copyFileURL, encryptionKey: configuration.encryptionKey)
} catch {
    return
}
```

and doing this in a backgroundtask will definitely help, a friendly advice is to always handle errors, you are just returning in the catch block, a log may help ..

Looking more into the doc I can see that RealmSwift integrates a compacting  feature now, more details here :
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#compacting-realms